# BigDecimal rounding not working properly in Jasper iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I have this defined in my iReport design as a variable:

```
$V{total_ver}.intValue() != 0 ? new BigDecimal((new BigDecimal( $F{TotalVerified}+"").divide( new BigDecimal( $V{total_ver} +"") , 4, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN )).multiply(new BigDecimal(100))+"")  : new BigDecimal(0)
```

It should display 90.91 but it displays 100.0000 instead.

I tested the equivalent in a Java program:

```
total_ver  != 0 ? new BigDecimal((new BigDecimal( TotalVerified+"").divide( new BigDecimal( total_ver +"") , 4, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN )).multiply(new BigDecimal(100))+"")  : new BigDecimal(0)
```

and it works fine(displays 90.91), so why does the expression fail to return the proper value in Jasper iReport?

Comment: Have you checked that the class of total_ver is java.math.BigDecimal? It might be a silly question, but better to check the obvious things first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems TotalVerified is not a String, and hence the constructor cannot set the precision. Bad if it is a double (should be avoided). When an int the precision is 0 digits.

```
new BigDecimal((new BigDecimal( $F{TotalVerified}+"").setScale(2)
```

The java version might have worked if TotalVerified was already a string with "90.91".

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression is very complex for doing something so simple as computing a percentage.  Try these steps instead:

Set the Initial Value Expressions for `$F{TotalVerified}` and `$V{total_ver}` to:
 `new java.math.BigDecimal(0.0)`

Use this expression instead of the one you originally had:

```
$V{total_ver}.intValue() != 0 ? $F{TotalVerified}.divide($V{total_ver}).multiply(100.0)
: new BigDecimal(0)
```